# Npgsql reading special characters from database

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I store data on a postgresql database (ver. 13.1) with special characters (polish, german: ß, ń, ł, ó...). Up to now I had never problem with reading them using Npgsql. In a new project these characters (saved on the database correctly) are transformed by encoding them incorrectly (e.g. \U0144, \xdf...). This appear regardless of the project (Xamarin, WPF). Below a short code snippet, that retrieves wrong encoded data.

```
            NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder { ... }.ToString());
            connection.Open();
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT name FROM stack ORDER BY id;", connection).ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            string asd = reader.GetString(0);
```

Comment: One eason is your view that you ae looking at the data is set to a different encoding, so code is good it is just the way you are looking at the data.  VS has a setting for encoding and it just may be you need to change the VS encoding.

Comment: All files are encoded in UTF-8 (the default option in VS). There is also no problem of displaying these characters in the whole application except in the shown situation.

Comment: Exactly why the encoding is wrong.  Normal encoding for characters 0x80 to 0xFF is based on your culture.  If you import data from another country these character are going to be display incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding problem was an effect of inserting data via pgAdmin, that uses a diffrent encoding than npgsql.